# ajaxFileUpload to Physical Path Root of C

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I'm using the ajaxfileupload control, and I want to save a file uploaded to the root of the C:\, but this code doesn't work.  I have set the NTFS Permissions to allow everyone/anonymous (this is a test environment), but it will still not save to this location:

```
ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs("C:\test123.pdf");
```

Saving to virtual directories works, but I want to be able to use a physical path like above.  Is this possible?

Comment: Describe "doesn't work". I'm not familiar with that particular exception.

Comment: Could be a UAC issue.  In newer versions of Windows (Windows 7+ I think does this), you get a UAC prompt when trying to create a file under the root.  Try just copy/pasting a file manually and see if you get the UAC prompt that says "You'll need to provide administator permission to move this folder".  NOTE: this prompt occurs even if you are already logged in with an account that is a local admin.  Does if work if you create a folder "C:\ajaxfileuploads" and try to save there?

Comment: Copying and pasting works.  Is this the proper syntax?  I have not found an example of saving to physical path without the use of ~/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i not understan why are you save on C!
Is not more simple make something like

```
ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/FolderTest/yourFilename.ext"))
```

Eventually when it is saved within the folder you can try to using file.move but howevere i still not understand why use an external("C drive") folder to test it ?

I hope it can help you.

UPDATE:

this code work really fine at my end :) without checking permission or any other stuff:

```
      Try
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\IMCFOLDER\" & FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex.Message & "FILENAME:" & FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName.ToString)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Exit Sub
```

if it solve your issue please mark it as answer

Comment: This is the syntax I see everywhere, using this syntax with a virtual path does indeed work.  I just want to know if it's possible to use a physical path instead.

Comment: Wait: when u upload a content(.txt,html,anything) your data are stored in tmp folder with save as it will be saved in the path that your choose BUT within your app (Server.MapPath) to achieve what you you need you need to apply special persmission to your user in this case you need to add Administrator to users of your app(and i'm not sure that could work for security reason). To do this go to your folder in example c:/youfolder right click security tab and the choose the roles that you need to add and give them permission to write there BUT IS NOT A GOOD IDEA :)

Comment: yes the NTFS perms are set to Everyone Full Control, UAC Disabled, and Anonymous Logon NTFS Full control to the folder.  So permissions are not the issue, has anyone actually used a physical path with the uploader?

Comment: Personaly no but i can check now

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finally getting this by putting the @ before the file path

```
string path = @"C:\" + e.FileName.ToString();
```

`ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path))`